# Backup and Restore using too much space

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, windows-backup

I'm on Windows 10 and using Backup and Restore. I'm not storing any system Images, but instead backing up files and folders. Following instructions on another post here, I completely wiped my earlier Backup and Restore settings in the registry and deleted all the data.

I attempted to backup my entire C-drive (150GB)
Artwork and Source Code (4GB - 20k files)
My Music Library (416GB - 55k files)

The destination drive had 1.36TB of free space. I would have expected it to use roughly 600GB of space (580 plus some overhead). The backup errored out 13 hours after it started at 57% done, completely using all 1.36TB.

What's going on here? Every file could have been written twice in the space I had, but it didn't even come close to backing it all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered what was going on. Inside Backup and Restore, I clicked the "Recover My Files" button to view the partial backup. I decided to browse by folder, and found that my E: drive which contains my ripped movie collection (this is a HTPC) was being backed up. This was baffling at first, because I had explicitly not selected to backup anything from the E-drive.

I re-ran the backup this time only backing up the User folders, and again noticed that the E-drive was being backed up. Then I realized that in backing up the users, the various Libraries were being backed up as well. I have no idea how this happened, but somehow the folder with my movies in it got added to the "Videos" library under my HTPC user account. I don't remember ever manually adding it there, but presumably it happened years ago on Win7. Of course Windows 10 hides libraries and the "Videos" folder explorer shows you is not the "Videos" library that Win 7 and 8 used.

I had to enable the option to view libraries, and then remove the E-drive folder from that library, and then reran the backup and while it hasn't finished running it's obviously using a sane amount of space.